# Influxdb Move Copy data between databases within Influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I have my_db1, my_db2, my_db3 in Influxdb, now is there a way to move or copy data between these databases with a query?

Answer (score 20):

InfluxQL provides an `INTO` clause that can be used to copy data between databases.

For example, if I had the point `cpu,host=server1 value=100 123` in `db_1` and wanted to copy that data to the point `new_cpu,host=server1 value=100 123` in `db_2`. I could issue the following query:

```
SELECT * INTO db_2..new_cpu FROM db_1..cpu group by *
```

For more information, see the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.12/query_language/data_exploration/#the-into-clause)

Comment: For any future reader, the reason for having that group by is this: If you use `SELECT *` with `INTO`, the query converts tags in the current measurement to fields in the new measurement. This can cause InfluxDB to overwrite points that were previously differentiated by a tag value. Use `GROUP BY <tag_key>` to preserve tags as tags.