# Rename MEASUREMENT

Tags: influxdb

I am using influxDB instead of MySQL for time series analysis. In my database `data`, I have a series which is called `/HFT/Data_HFT/OrderBook/DCIX_OB`. That name is irrelevant and it was created by error. That series has 89 million lines, so it would be very long to recreate that series.

So this is not a solution for me:

```
SELECT * INTO new_name FROM old_name
DROP MEASUREMENT old_name
```

I tried that [solution](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4155), but it didn't work at all. Here is the error :

```
> RENAME MEASUREMENTS 'OLD_NAME' to 'NEW_NAME'
ERR: error parsing query: found RENAME, expected SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL at line 1, char 1
```

How could I rename it?

Comment: AFAIK, InfluxDB still doesn't support series rename.

Comment: That solution is also [wrong](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4155#issuecomment-304221824).

Comment: This solution works SELECT * INTO new_name FROM old_name do copy and paste the old name(to avoid case mismatch) where it is showing time and written status.

Comment: WARNING: The solution `SELECT * INTO new_name FROM old_name` will convert all your tags into fields of type string and your data will be corrupt. There is no current way to rename. To do the copy properly, see my solution below.

Answer (score 12):

There is no official way to rename a measurement yet. The way to do it is:

1. Find all tags in your measurement using `SHOW TAG KEYS FROM MyMeasurement`. Let's assume your tags were `tag1` and `tag2`
2. Copy all data into a new measurement using `SELECT * INTO MyMeasurementCopy from MyMeasurement GROUP BY tag1,tag2`
3. Once you are 100% sure all data is copied, you can drop the old data using `DROP MEASUREMENT MyMeasurement`

It's a long process but it works.

Comment: You can use `SELECT * INTO MyMeasurementCopy from MyMeasurement GROUP BY *` to avoid the manual process of finding all the tags.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084262/1658010

Comment: That would be awesome if it works! I hope it does not convert all fields into tags. If anyone has tried this, would be great to know.

Comment: I can confirm it works. Tested in influx version 1.7.9.

Answer (score 2):

*Adapted from [@Sarang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60563982/4653485) and comments.*

There is no `RENAME` operation but you can copy a measurement into another, then delete it.

```
SELECT * INTO DestMeasurementCopy from SrcMeasurement GROUP BY *
DROP MEASUREMENT SrcMeasurement
```

`GROUP BY *` ensures the tags are preserved. See [this answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084262/4653485).